# Segmentation fault on break statement?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, segmentation-fault, switch-statement

I'm just going through a switch statement:

```
case RoutingMessage::FWDMESSAGE:
        {
                //Message Format:
                //@FromNode~12~DestNode.from x to y hops .<the message>
                int destID;
                string changableStr, finalMessage;
                string buf(iter->second);
                string delim = ".";
                destID = atoi(buf.substr(0, buf.find(delim)).c_str());
                buf.erase(0, buf.find(delim) + delim.length());

                changableStr = buf.substr(0, buf.find(delim));

                stringstream sstm;
                sstm << changableStr << " " << myID-3700;
                changableStr = sstm.str();
                buf.erase(0, buf.find(delim) + delim.length());

                string theMsg = buf.substr(0, buf.find(delim));

                stringstream sstm2;
                sstm2 << changableStr << "." << theMsg;
                finalMessage = sstm2.str();

                cout << "FINAL MESSAGE: " << finalMessage << endl;

                if(myID == destID)
                    cout << "\t\t\tMINE\n";
                    //PrintMessage(iter->)
                else
                {
                    neighbor.sin_port = forwardingTable.at(destID).begin()->first;
                    char *cstr = new char[finalMessage.length() + 1];
                    strcpy(cstr, finalMessage.c_str());
                    char* buf;
                    sprintf(buf, "@%d~%d~%d.%s", myID, RoutingMessage::FWDMESSAGE, destID, cstr);
                    SendMessage(neighbor, buf);
                }
                cout << "test\n";
                break;
                cout << "test2\n";
            }
```

But, when I hit the `break;` gdb spits out:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__GI___libc_free (mem=0x32317e3130373340) at malloc.c:2892
2892    malloc.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) backtrace
#0  __GI___libc_free (mem=0x32317e3130373340) at malloc.c:2892
#1  0x00007ffff7b43cab in std::ios_base::~ios_base() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#2  0x00007ffff7b6ea13 in std::basic_stringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_stringstream() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
```

I've never seen this... can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are `sprintf`ing to an unallocated buffer here:

```
char* buf;
sprintf(buf, "@%d~%d~%d.%s", myID, RoutingMessage::FWDMESSAGE, destID, cstr);
```

Comment: So strange - you're right, I totally was... but why did this crash on the `break` and not on my `sprintf()`? I was actually able to send the correct buffer to my other nodes, before this one crashed.

Comment: Given that `char* buf;` is unitialized and being overwritten, I'm guessing `undefined behavior' applies - the possibilities are mindboggling :)

Comment: @MrDuk on `break` (or, generally, on block ending) destructors called for every local object that leaving scope. You had undefined data in `buf` pointer and overwritten some memory - somewhere; in your case, it appears that this overwrite have corrupted malloc's markers. You're actually lucky that your program crashed so soon - so you can find problem easily and fix it.